# the time performance of inserting into a hash table using external chaining

Tags: performance, hash, linked-list

Suppose I am going to inset a new element into a hash table using External Chaining. If the table is with resizing, I know the time of the insert operation is big theta 1.

However, I don't understand why the performance is different if the bucket is of fixed size. Shouldn't it be inserting into a linked list, which is also big theta 1?

This is from the slide of CS61B @UCB.

[image: this is from the slide of CS61B @UCB]

Answer (score 0):

The "fixed size" vs "resizing" refers to the number of buckets, rather than the size of each individual bucket.

The idea is that if we have a fixed number of buckets, let's say `k` buckets, and we insert `n` elements into the hash table, then with a hash function with perfect spread, each bucket will hold `k/n` elements in it.

Since it would take us `O(k/n)` to look through all of the items in the bucket, and `k` is just a constant because it is fixed, our lookup time is `O(n)`.